# Fixed footer not working on iOS devices and Galaxy Tab

Tags: html, css, iphone

I have managed to make the footer fixed in my web page.

I used the following in my CSS file:

```
#footer
{
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   bottom:0px;
}
```

This works in all major browsers (IE 8, Safari, Firefox).

However, when I test this page on iOS Device (iPod & iPad) and Galaxy tab, this does not make the footer fixed at the bottom. Rather, when the page scrolls, the footer also scrolls up / down with it.

Can anybody help me with this issue. I want to ensure that if it works for mobile clients then it does not break the currently behaviour on desktop browsers. In short a solution working for both.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Bart Kiers: I agree... Its not advisable to accept answers which actually does not solve the problem.. If done, this would mislead other who come across the same issue.. However, I do ensure myself that the answer(s) to my question(s) which actually helps, I do vote them & accept the answer.. @Niklas: you shouldn't have made this useless comment... rather you would have provided a solution :-)

Comment: @Niklas, yeah, I missed the other two pages of the OP's questions, no need to act like a smart ass here. My point still remains that you can't force others to go accept answers, or else they don't get answered. 68% is a decent number.

Comment: `(hard to accept one in that case, wouldn't you agree?)` - A smart ass comment with the wrong facts set me off, sorry. But let's drop this and move on.

Comment: guys, please leave it off here.. I suggest we better concentrate on the question. Would appreciate & accept the answer if any of you can help me with this issue.. Thanks!

Comment: @Niklas, yes, I must confess that that remark triggered something. I forgot a smiley/wink after it. I meant it as a joke/tongue-in-cheek-remark. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I solved the problem myself. Like the code which I posted in the question works well on all modern desktop browsers.

I used `iScroll`. The problem with `iScroll` was that it was not working properly with `Firefox 3.6`. So what I did is when I detect the browser as `Firefox`, I set the `id` of the `wrapper` of `iScroll` to `""` (empty string). This causes the browser to use the earlier code.

This is how it got working in all desktop + mobile browsers.

Hope this helps to others,

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

example http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/simple/

**but it has some problems**

- Form fields compatibility
- Zoom glitches
- Better desktop browser compatibility
- onScroll event
- hash and hash change support (ie:
  http://example.com/#element-id)
- automatic refresh upon DOM change

Comment: The example (http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/simple/) does not work in firefox.. did you test it yourself?

Comment: @mahendraaliya - I've already mentioned in my answer. it doesn't have good support for desktops